# Keyclock 17.0.0 - Quarkus theme with npm packages

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-component, keycloak, keycloak-services

I used keycloak legacy theme implementation with Vuejs. But with the keycloak 17.0 (Quarkus) not working as expected. How can we add npm packages to keycloak theme?

In keycloak legacy, we can use like below method to add npm packages.

For login, admin console, and old account console

```
cd src/main/resources/theme/keycloak/common/resources
npm install some-package-name@version
git add package-lock.json
cd -
```

But this methodologic is not working with the keycloak new version.

more info: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/themes/UPDATING-NODE-MODULES.md

Comment: What is not working as expected? What did you tried so far? Do you have a [repro]? Did you read the changelogs?

Comment: They didn't mention that @kissu

Comment: Every changelog is available here: https://www.keycloak.org/blog-archive.html

Comment: Still not aper anything in this doc.

Comment: What was your previous version? Check the differences between the former one and the 17.0.1 one. There are migrations details down there.

Comment: Keycloak has two versions in 17.0.0 


A. Keycloak(17.0.0) Distribution powered by Quarkus
B. Keycloak WildFly (deprecated) (17.0.0) Distribution powered by WildFly

My old implimentation compatible with B but not with A